# File Upload not Working when form send data to another php file through jquery

Tags: php, file-upload

Below code works well when I am executing PHP in same page but it does not work when I execute script_add_business.php using jquery. Particularly HTML html file upload does not send any value but when I tried getting other fields values like textbox, I am successfully getting them.

**MY HTML:**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addBusinessForm" class="form-horizontal addBusinessForm" action="">
<input type="file" name="logo" class="form-control">
<button type="submit" id="addBusiness" class="btn btn-custom">Upload Logo</button>
</form>
```

**JQUERY within HTML page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Add Invoice Form
    $('#addBusiness').click(function() {
      $.post("script_add_business.php", $(".addBusinessForm").serialize(), function(response) {
        $('#success').html(response);
        $('#success').show();
        if (response == 'OK') {
            $('#addBusinessForm')[0].reset();
            $('#success').text('Your Business has been successfully submitted. People can see it live once we approve it.');
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
    </script>
```

**script_add_business.php CODE:**

```
if(!empty($_FILES['logo']['name']))
        {
            $target_dir = "uploads/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["logo"]["name"]);
            $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $imgname = basename($_FILES["logo"]["name"]);
            $target_file = $target_dir .$imgname;
            echo "File path is:". $target_file; exit;
}
```

I really appreciate help.

Comment: Maybe have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this url's, these may help you

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/8758614/1072492
>
> http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload file with jQuery $.post method.

Try like this .

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addBusinessForm" class="form-horizontal addBusinessForm" action="">
        <input type="file" name="logo" class="form-control">
        <button type="submit" id="addBusiness" class="btn btn-custom">Upload Logo</button>
    </form>


$('#addBusiness').click(function() {

            var formData=new FormData();

            formData.append("image",$('[name="logo"]')[0].files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'script_add_business.php',
                data:formData,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType:"JSON",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success:function(response){ 
                    // Do stuffffff
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```